# How to return specific information in xml?

Tags: xml, grep

I have a bunch of .xml file in a folder, and I would like to extract specific information from it. I intend to use grep in command line

This is part of the xml file of my example,

```
   <component>
  <structuredBody>
     <component>
        <section>
           <id root="d38bc14a-d64c-4a8f-a917-459725918ede"/>
           <code code="48780-1" displayName="SPL LISTING DATA ELEMENTS SECTION" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"/>
           <effectiveTime value="20160629"/>
           <subject>
              <manufacturedProduct>
                 <manufacturedProduct>
                    <code code="68196-157" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.69"/>
                    <name>Aspirin<suffix>regular strength</suffix>
                    </name>
                    <formCode code="C42998" **displayName="TABLET"** codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.26.1.1"/>
                    <asEntityWithGeneric>
                       <genericMedicine>
                          **<name>aspirin</name>**
                       </genericMedicine>
                    </asEntityWithGeneric>
                    <ingredient classCode="ACTIB">
                       <quantity>
                          <numerator unit="mg" value="325"/>
                          <denominator unit="1" value="1"/>
                       </quantity>
                       <ingredientSubstance>
                          <code code="R16CO5Y76E" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.4.9"/>
                          <name>ASPIRIN</name>
                          <activeMoiety>
                             <activeMoiety>
                                <code code="R16CO5Y76E" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.4.9"/>
```

I want the displayName="Tablet" in formCode (line 14) and < name > aspirin < /name > after < genericMedicine > (line 17). 
This is my code

```
grep -A 10 "subject" *.xml | grep -e "formCode" -e "genericMedicine"  > output
```

But the result turn out that the < name > aspirin < /name > is not shown, and the < /genericMedicine > is shown. How can I get just the displayName="tablet" and aspirin?

Comment: Are you allowed to use other tools, there is [xml_grep](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep), specifically made for search in xml files.

Comment: Yes, but I am not familiar with that, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I want the "TABLET" and "aspirin" from the location I mentioned.

Comment: `grep` will only output the entire matching line (or collection of lines when using the `-A` option).  If you only want specific text from that line, you need to use a different tool.

Comment: Also, this `grep` search will output multiple hits if there is more than one `<subject>` element anywhere in the file.

Comment: I understand that. I just want to know how can I get this two information in one output using grep or other tools, even it is a line. I can manipulate it later.

Comment: `grep` really isn't suited to what you're trying to do.  Are you open to other tools?  Does it have to be all via the command line (I assume Linux)?  And do the `<name>` and `<displayName>` values have to be output in one operation?  What do you want to have happen if the file contains multiple such value pairs?

Comment: It is okay to have those < displayName > and other stuff shown in the result, i can process that using other tools